# I am copying files from one folder to another but i want to copy files of particular date, if they exist

Tags: vbscript

Below is what I am doing:

```
For each file in objFolder.Files
  path1 = filesys.getabsolutepathname(objFolder&"\"&File.name)
  Set objFile = filesys.GetFile(path1)
  mdate = left(cdate(objFile.DateLastModified),8)
  If datevalue(mdate) = datevalue(cdate(arrdate(i)))  then
    filesys.copyfile path1, dest1
  else   
  end if
Next
```

the code fails if the file with particular date doesn't exist in that folder.

Comment: Debug it, check objFile is what you think, check value of DateLastModified is what you think? Please comment in some examples of values in your code for us

Answer (score 0):

here is a suggestion. Maybe it will solve your question; at least I hope this helps.

```
For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
    mdate = left(cstring(objFile.DateLastModified),10)
    If datevalue(mdate) = datevalue(cdate(arrdate(i))) then
        objFile.copy dest1
    End If
Next
```